# ggplot with linear regression, beta coefficient per year

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have a dataframe called `df` with a `date` and an `age` variable. I want to plot these variables, add a linear regression line and the corresponding formula.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, age)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y~x) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 years", date_labels = "%Y") +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               label.x.npc = "middle", label.y.npc = "top",
               formula = y~x, parse = TRUE)
```

**Plot**

[image]

However, I feel that the beta coefficient is per day, while I want it to represent the change in y per year. How can I change this within `stat_poly_eq`?

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(14086, 14261, 14742, 14633, 
                                         15475, 15060, 15191, 16807, 16554, 16729, 17906, 17509), class = "Date"), 
                     age = c(26L, 28L, 34L, 36L, 42L, 45L, 52L, 58L, 60L, 66L, 
                             68L, 70L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `date` format to `year`; this will accordingly alter the interpretation.
Like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

df$year <- as.numeric(format(df$date, "%Y"))

ggplot(df, aes(year, age)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x)+
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
                 aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
                 parse = TRUE, label.x.npc = "left")+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The **coefficient of 4.20** for the year indicates that **with each incremental increase of one year**, there is an **expected rise in age by 4.20 units**. This straightforward finding points to a linear correlation between the year and age, demonstrating that as time moves forward, age correspondingly increases.

Comment: This aligns all the points to the corresponding year, so I lose a lot of granularity (day, month). How would I preserve this granularity, but get the regression line per year?